# After animating my text with CSS3, why does it not completely disappear?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

When the words Front End finishes animating, a little bit of it can be seen on the top portion of the div with a class of .wrapper. The only thing I've been able to figure out how to fix the issue is by making it a smaller font size. How can I fix the issue with keeping the element the size that it currently is?

```css
body{
 background: lightblue;
}
.wrapper{
 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 padding:5%; 
}
.frontEnd{
 -webkit-animation: move 2s ease-in-out normal;
   animation: move 2s ease-in-out normal;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move{
 0% {transform: translate(100%, 25%);}
 100%{transform: translate(7%, 25%);}
}
.webDeveloper{
 transform: translate(0%, 45%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>header animations</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
   <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 818 323.15">
    <defs>
     <style>
      .frontEnd {
       font-size: 101px;
       fill: #a4844e;
       font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Thin, Brandon Grotesque;
       font-weight: 200;
      }

      .webDeveloper {
       font-size: 70px;
       fill: #336699;
       font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Medium, Brandon Grotesque;
       font-weight: 500;
      }

      .webGraphics {
       font-size: 55px;
       fill: #a4844e;
       font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Thin, Brandon Grotesque;
       font-weight: 200;
      }
     </style>
    </defs>
    <title>creativeCogAnimation</title>
    <g><text class="frontEnd">FRONT END</text></g>
    <g><text class="webDeveloper">
      <tspan class="webDeveloper">WEB DEVELOPER</tspan>
     </text></g>
    <g><text class="webGraphics" transform="translate(313 274.65)">web &amp; graphic design</text></g>
   </svg>
  </h1>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what prompted you to use SVG here?

Comment: The animation is going to go into a header and might have some other parts to it, like a background image, when I get done with it. If it does just end up being text, I suppose using a regular h1 without the SVG would be more appropriate. Do you think it's what is causing my text to do that?

Comment: Not necessarily-- sometimes you do get unexpected results when using SVG in places you'd traditionally see HTML, so I wouldn't rule it out, but I asked more to understand and get context.

Comment: I did some testing and it's not the SVG. I can see what it's doing when I don't use the SVG. Before the animation begins, it's higher up on the screen. Once the animation starts it drops further down on the page and when it's finished it goes back to its original place higher up on the screen, so it's getting cut off.  What I did to fix it is, and I don't know if it's a correct way since I don't know much about animations, but I set the transform: translate property where I wanted it to be positioned on the screen before the animation begins and not just in the keyframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this help you.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.frontEnd {
  -webkit-animation: move 2s ease-in-out normal;
  animation: move 2s ease-in-out normal;
  transform: translate(0%, 25%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100%, 25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0%, 25%);
  }
}

.webDeveloper {
  transform: translate(0%, 45%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 818 323.15">
    <defs>
     <style>
      .frontEnd {
       font-size: 101px;
       fill: #a4844e;
       font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Thin, Brandon Grotesque;
       font-weight: 200;
      }

      .webDeveloper {
       font-size: 70px;
       fill: #336699;
       font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Medium, Brandon Grotesque;
       font-weight: 500;
      }

      .webGraphics {
       font-size: 55px;
       fill: #a4844e;
       font-family: BrandonGrotesque-Thin, Brandon Grotesque;
       font-weight: 200;
      }
     </style>
    </defs>
    <title>creativeCogAnimation</title>
    <g><text class="frontEnd" >FRONT END</text></g>
      
    <g><text class="webDeveloper">
      <tspan class="webDeveloper">WEB DEVELOPER</tspan>
     </text></g>
    <g><text class="webGraphics" transform="translate(313 274.65)">web &amp; graphic design</text></g>
   </svg>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, if you see the comment from up above I realized I needed to set the transform: translate outside the keyframes . Thanks!